# How to get user_posts permission from facebook approved

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have an app where I want to show recent user facebook post into user's story. But Facebook is not approving this use case and saying this

[image]

So I need to know what is the best use case for this particular functionality to make it approved. I am flexible and can implement any functionality in the app just to make sure I get this permission.

Comment: "I am flexible and can implement any functionality in the app just to make sure I get this permission". Is not strange at all. Sounds like you are going to use it for something bad but you will implement something Facebook allows so you get approved.

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook docs tells you for each permission what´s a valid use case and what´s not. Here´s the information for the `user_posts` permission: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-user_posts